# Titanium Alloy Push Notifications - passing function as callback to be called inside event listener

Tags: callback, push-notification, titanium, addeventlistener, titanium-alloy

I have set up a module for dealing with Push-Notifications which has this:

```
//myPush module
var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush'); 
...
        var setAppPushNotifications = function(cback) {
            // Process incoming push notifications
            log('cback=' + typeof cback);  //log is a wrapper to Ti.API.info
            CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function (evt,cback) {
                log('Inside CloudPush-Callback.');
                log('cback=' + typeof cback); 
                getIncomingNotification(evt, cback);
            });
        };
        var getIncomingNotification = function(evt,cback) {
            //return if zero payload 
            //test for app required basic fields
            log('cback=' + typeof cback); 
            cback(evt.payload);
        };
```

**Scenario**: I use it inside a Controller, so that I can pass a callback that is Controller related (for example, after callback processing I want to close the controller/views and open another one):

```
//controller code
var myPush = Alloy.Globals.myPush; 
...
    myPush.setAppPushNotifications(processNotificationPayload);

    function processNotificationPayload(p) {
        //select notification channel
        //do some processing...
        //close controller and view and get back to index.
    }
```

The problem is: **cback** function is not been passed along, or, by the time of **CloudPush-callback** event is called, **cback** doesn't exists anymore.
I got the following logs:

```
[myPush.js][setAppPushNotifications]: cback=function
[myPush.js][setAppPushNotifications]: cback=undefined
[myPush.js][getIncomingNotification]: cback=undefined
```

**What would be a solution respecting the given scenario** ? 
Please show me some code. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one....

```
//myPush module
var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush'); 
...
        var setAppPushNotifications = function(cback) {
            // Process incoming push notifications
            log('cback=' + typeof cback);  //log is a wrapper to Ti.API.info
            CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function (evt) {
                log('Inside CloudPush-Callback.');
                log('cback=' + typeof cback); 
                getIncomingNotification(evt,cback);
            });
        };
        var getIncomingNotification = function(evt,cback) {
            //return if zero payload 
            //test for app required basic fields
            log('cback=' + typeof cback); 
            cback(evt.payload);
        };
```

Comment: Amazing how 10 hours of programming can muddy your vision. Thank you. Can you explain why it did not work the original way?

Comment: of course,CloudPush has a callback listener which returns only one value from its callback but you are setting 2 values in its callback with same name as cback.

Comment: Thanks, actually I've put getIncomingNotification inside setAppPushNotifications to exclude the second parameter (cback).

Comment: Hi, Can you please suggest me how to handle this `callback` function in the best possible way. Right now it is in my alloy.js file. But the case can be any screen of my app may be open so how to stop the user from doing any action until the push notification has been processed.