# Titanium Alloy Push Notification Subscribed But Listener Not firing Up

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I need to make a push notification listener, My code for this is below and it runs perfect till the subscription and the dashboard confirms it is subscribed successfully, but the problem occurs with the receiver.

```js
Alloy.Globals.ServiceAddress = "my service address";
Ti.API.info("1");
var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
var Cloud = require("ti.cloud");
var deviceToken = null;

loginUser(); // flow starts from here
function loginUser() {
  Cloud.Users.login({
    login: 'User',
    password: 'Password'
  }, function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
      var user = e.users[0];
      //    alert("Loggin successfully");
      getDeviceToken();
    } else {
      alert("Error2*** :" + e.message);
      //Ti.API.info('error ')
    }
  });
}

function getDeviceToken() {

  if (Ti.Platform.Android) {
    CloudPush.debug = true;
    CloudPush.focusAppOnPush = false;
    CloudPush.enabled = true;
    CloudPush.showAppOnTrayClick = true;
    CloudPush.showTrayNotification = true;
    CloudPush.singleCallback = true;
    CloudPush.singleCallback = true;
    CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
      success: deviceTokenSuccess,
      error: deviceTokenError
    });
  }
}

// Enable push notifications for this device
// Save the device token for subsequent API calls
function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
  deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
  alert(e.deviceToken);
  subscribeToChannel(deviceToken);
}

function deviceTokenError(e) {
  alert('Failed to register for push notifications! ' + e.error);
}

// Process incoming push notifications
function subscribeToChannel(deviceToken) {

  // Subscribes the device to the 'news_alerts' channel
  // Specify the push type as either 'android' for Android or 'ios' for iOS
  Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribeToken({
    device_token: deviceToken,
    channel: 'Vision', //'You_App',
    type: Ti.Platform.name == 'android' ? 'android' : 'ios'
  }, function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
      alert('Subscribed');
      SendNotification(deviceToken);
    } else {
      // indicator.visible = false;
      alert('Subscribe Error:\n' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
  });
}

function SendNotification(to_deviceToken) {
  alert('sendnot');
  Cloud.PushNotifications.notifyTokens({
    channel: 'My Cannel',
    to_tokens: to_deviceToken,
    payload: 'Welcome to push notifications'
  }, function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
      alert('Success Send');
    } else {
      alert('Send Error:\n' +
        ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
  });
}
```

**When I add event-listener to push notifications it doesn't even fire up however, the client is saying it is connected.**

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function (evt) {
    alert('rec');
    alert("Notification received: " + evt.payload);
});
CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickLaunchedApp', function (evt) {
    Ti.API.info('Tray Click Launched App (app was not running)');
});
CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickFocusedApp', function (evt) {
    Ti.API.info('Tray Click Focused App (app was already running)');
});
```

PS. I have searched and already read related threads [Like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759254/titanium-alloy-push-notifications-passing-function-as-callback-to-be-called-in?rq=1)

I am attaching the log to make it clarify that subscription and notification send is working properly
[Push notification Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZX1E.png)
and
[Connected Clients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6cKb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved 
I was compiling with titanium api level 4.1.1.v20151203143424 with CloudPush module version 3.2.1
I migrated to titanium 6.0.0.v20160202173231 with cloudpush module version 3.4.1 
and all set see in [this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46TbV.png)